# My Ubuntu 12.04.2 Online Accounts only has Google and Windows Live accounts. Where are the others?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, online-accounts

I just reinstalled ubuntu 12.04, fully updated it and I went to set up my online accounts. It only has two account types to add, Google and windows live accounts. There is no option to add facebook, or any of the others that used to show up. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall account-plugin-facebook

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-facebook
```

Or you can try to install all account plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-*
```